# Can't use the added function in Repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j 2.4.4 for my project. This is some in project:

**User**:

[image]

**UserRepository**:

[image]

I can still use the built-in functions in Repository such as save(), findAll(),... but when I add and use some functions, for example "existsByUsername", it has error:

```
11:53:26.562 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] WARN  o.s.d.n.c.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator - Don't know how to translate exception of type class org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.NoSuchRecordException
```

Then, I try to add query for function, it is still
[image]

Could you help me to determine this error and give me a solution? Thank you!\

*Updated:*
I call API in Postman, I received this result while my DB has only 1 user:

```
{
    "error": "Records with more than one value cannot be converted without a mapper.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Records with more than one value cannot be converted without a mapper."
}
```

Comment: Your Query throws this exception: NoSuchRecordException which means that there is no user with this username

Comment: No. I passed username which have been created. I tried query in console, it can return true or false. but when using in repository, it has above error.

Comment: Please add code as code and not as images.

Answer (score 1):

As your exception states, no record is returned from Neo4j and thus it cannot be mapped to a Boolean.

Best would be to use `Optional<User>` and check with `isPresent()`

```
@Query("MATCH (n:User {username: $username}) RETURN n")
Optional<User> existsForUsername(String username);
```

That said, it is already handled by Spring Data without using a custom query :

```
boolean existsByUsername(String username);
```

Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject

Comment: I did both but it has same error. I use Spring Data Neo4j and OGM for NodeEntity and RelationshipEntity, does it has conflict?

Comment: All added functions to repository are unusable

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather obscure set of references on github site for the NEO4J Spring Data: [here](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAGRAPH/issues/DATAGRAPH-1472?filter=allopenissues)

It seems that the existsBy property was omitted. It is being fixed, but whether that has made it to the Spring Data repository is another matter. You don;t say which version of the Spring-boot-starter-neo4j you are using, but you may care to use this one and see if it works;

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: My current version is 2.4.4. All added functions to repository are unusable. I am also using Neo4j OGM to create NodeEntity and RelationshipEntity, does it have confllict with Spring Data Neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the other answers here are right. But, if you're using Spring Boot 2.4.4, OGM is no longer supported. It now uses a model called SDN (or at least it was when it was under development). You may just have a dependency issue.  Here's part of my Gradle build file, these should be all the dependencies you need:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    application
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}
```

Comment: but SDN does't support RelationshipEntity, so I need to use OGM

Comment: It supports a similar thing - RelationshipProperties: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.annotations.relationship.